# kubernetes execute a command in a env. varible with eval

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, eval

I would like to execute a command in a container (let it be *ls*) then read the exit code with *echo $?*
`kubectl exec -ti mypod -- bash -c "ls; echo $?"` does not work because it returns the exit code of my current shell not the one of the container.

So I tried to use *eval* on a env varible I defined in my manifest :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - container2
    image: varunuppal/nonrootsudo
    env:
    - name: resultCmd
      value: 'echo $?'
```

then `kubectl exec -ti mypod -- bash -c "ls;eval $resultCmd"` but the eval command does not return anything.

```
bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
```

Note that I can run these two commands within the container

```
kubectl exec -ti mypod bash
#ls;eval $resultCmd
bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
**0**
```

How can I make it work?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you use double quotes instead of single ones.
Single quotes won't substitute anything, but double quotes will.

From the bash documentation:

> [3.1.2.2 Single
> Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)
>
> Enclosing characters in single quotes (`'`) preserves the literal
> value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not
> occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

To summarize, this is how your command should look like:

```
kubectl exec -ti firstpod -- bash -c 'ls; echo $?'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the POSIX shell `eval` command is wrong 99.999% of the time. Even if you ignore the presence of Kubernetes in this question. The problem in your question is that your `kubectl` command is expanding the definition of `$resultCmd` in the shell you ran the `kubectl` command. Specifically due to your use of double-quotes. That interactive shell has no knowledge of the definition of `$resultCmd` in your "manifest" file. So that shell replaces `$resultCmd` with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kurtis Rader and Thomas for your answers.

It also works when I precede the $? with a backslash :

```
kubectl exec -ti firstpod -- bash -c "ls; echo \$?"
```